# How to stream data in recursion function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, recursion

My goal is to crawl all messages from O365 using MS Graph API and Node.js.
First I am getting the root folders, then I am making iteration over root folders and get messages and if there are the child folders the childrenFoldersRequest function executed. This function calls it self in recursion if there are more child folders. 
All works great, but the result object I am storing in memory and write this result to json file. It may cause performance issues in the future. How can I pipe all recursion responses and stream it to result json file?

```
function getMessages(accessToken, callback) {
  https.get(options, function (response) {
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function (d) {
      body += d;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
    var error;
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      var mailFolders = JSON.parse(body).value,
        resultObject = {},
        resultFolder = {};
      callback(null, JSON.parse(body));

      // Iterate through mail folders and get messages for each folder
      asyncIterator(mailFolders, function (path, next) {
        var config = {
          skip: 0
        };
        // Get messages for folder
        messageRequest(accessToken, path.id, config.skip, resultFolder, function (messages) {
          resultObject[path.displayName] = messages;
          // If folder has child folders
          if (path.childFolderCount) {
            resultObject[path.displayName].innerFolders = {};
            // Get children folders
            childrenFoldersRequest(accessToken, path.id, resultObject[path.displayName].innerFolders, function (childFolders) {
            next();
          });
        } else {
          next();
        }

      });
    }, function () {
      callback(null, resultObject);
    });
  }
});
```

And the childrenFoldersRequest function:

```
function childrenFoldersRequest(accessToken, folderId, resultObject, callback) {
  https.get(options, function (response) {
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function (d) {
      body += d;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
      var error;
      if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        // Iterate through child folders
        asyncIterator(JSON.parse(body).value, function (path, next) {

          resultObject[path.displayName] = {};
          var resultFolder = {};
          var config = {
            skip: 0
          };
          // Get messages from folder
          messageRequest(accessToken, path.id, config.skip, resultFolder, function (messages) {

          resultObject[path.displayName].messages = messages;
          // If folder has child folders
          if (path.childFolderCount) {
            resultObject[path.displayName].innerFolders = {};
            // make recursive function call if we have child folders 
            childrenFoldersRequest(accessToken, path.id, resultObject[path.displayName].innerFolders, function (childFolders) {
            next();
          });
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    }, function () {
      callback(JSON.parse(body));
    });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a 'cache' functional approach of this.
Initialize your stream on a closure (on the top accessible level)
Then, at each iteration you'll add the next information on it.

Maybe use highland for your stream, it's great :)

I hope i helped

Comment: Thank you for response. Also I need to paste new data(objects that I am retrieving on each iteration) to the some parts of first streamed data, not append data to the end of the file. How could I achieve this?

Comment: hum I see, maybe create a stream by iteration in addition of a main stream, and call the specific stream needed. For do that, you must create a stream pointing list where each stream will be identify by an id (the folderName for exemple). At the end of your recursive function, each "mini-stream" will source the main stream... If you cannot do that, use some tools focus on big data processing... ? sorry i cannot help more :(